# Global Zimbra filter for incoming email (not spam)

Tags: zimbra

We ran across a situation at our company in that we need to have all emails that come from a certain domain to be redirected to a certain account.

Other than creating a script to loop through all my accounts and setup a filter (got one ready, just don't want to actually use it because maintaining might be a pain), is there any way to do this globally for the entire server/domain?

Comment: I do not see how as such filters are per account

Comment: But spam filtering is made at server level right?
So shouldnt I be able to put a filter at the same level?

Comment: Spam filter is created in spamassassin. If you are happy to edit by hand this config - go. Nevertheless I am not sure you can create what you want there

Comment: I guess I didnt explain it well. I meant that if spamassassin can do it at that level, shouldnt I be able to plug something else in there to do the same thing? What I need is a solution where I can specify a filter to send a copy of an email to my monitoring address, and then the usual flow of the email would continue (->spamassassin->blablabla->mailbox)

Comment: I am afraid my knowledge is not enough to help you with such solution

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying :) Hopefully someone might be able to shed some light on this issue.